# Can anyone identify this power resistor?

Tags: power, resistors, identification

[image: Power Resistor]

I'm trying to identify this power resistor.

Comment: As in who made it?

Comment: What problem are you having? Are you asking for the component value? There are thousands of online resistor colour code calculators.

Comment: It's very generically looking, but with a very standard color-coded marking. So you can easily derive it's value, but probably impossible to tell who the manufacturer is or part number whatsoever.

Comment: Have tried the online calculator route. To be honest, not sure if I'm looking at orange, brown or red color rings. Looking for the component value.

Comment: The colors on the photo can definitely be misleading, but I presume you have the part in hand? If you do and having trouble identifying the colors, than ask someone else. FWIW, the bottom ring looks more "brown" than the top one, which looks orange to me (but it could be red too..).

Comment: I read it as 0.2 ohm 1%

Comment: " I read it as 0.2 ohm 1%" Thats what I came up with. Can't find a replacement of that value anywhere that I've searched.

Comment: If it is a power resistor, than it's power rating matters, but isn't encoded in the colors. Can be estimated through it's size though.

Comment: `Can't find a replacement [for 0.2 Ω multiwatt]` Consider 2\*0.1 Ω.

Comment: [Mouser](https://www.mouser.ca/c/passive-components/resistors/?resistance=200%20mOhms&termination%20style=Axial&tolerance=1%20%25)  or [Digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/through-hole-resistors/53?s=N4IgjCBcpgbFoDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRAGYwB2MATgAYQBdAgBwBcoQBldgJwCWAOwDmIAL4EATPQAcAVgQhkkdNnxFSIGfQAEAWwDyAC31ZmbTpBABVIQPaGUAWRxosAVz44Jk7VvoAOildQlNmcSA) Are you looking on an electronics sales site?